# SSH keeps requesting my password if I use a keyfile other than default

Tags: ssh, public-key

I have a keyfile named `KEY`, which has `KEY` and `KEY.pub`. I upload the pub to `authorized_keys`, and add the private with

```
ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/KEY
```

But when I try to connect with `ssh user@host.com`, it keeps asking me for the password.

If I generate a key with `ssh-keygen` and leave the default key name, uploading the pub and loading the private, it *does not* request a password.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `ssh -vvv user@host.com` you can get the debug output and it will probably tell you that it can't authenticate with `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (ssh's default key file). The answer is to tell ssh which key to use:

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/KEY user@host.com
```

You can also add your per-host keyfile to your `.ssh/config`, then you'll just have to type `ssh host.com` and user/key are selected automatically.

**Example entry for .ssh/config** (For more information see `man ssh_config`):

```
Host mysshserver ssh.host.com
HostName ssh.host.com
User myusername
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykeyfile
```

**Explanation of keyfiles  from `man ssh`:**

```
 -i identity_file
             Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or
             DSA authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
             protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for pro‐
             tocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-
             host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
             multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in config‐
             uration files).
```

Comment: I'm getting a bad configuration option when adding the ssh -i line:

/home/gabriel/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: ssh

Comment: @Gabriel: "ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/KEY user@host.com" works only from the commandline. The configfile option is different and I've updated my answer with an example entry for the .ssh/config file.

Answer (score 1):

To set up your key files correctly (How-To [here](http://wp.uberdose.com/2006/10/16/ssh-automatic-login/)), note the following:

In case your host `.ssh` directory and files don't have the right permissions AND / OR your remote user home directory doesn't have the right permissions, ssh will keep asking for password although it finds the key file.

You can see if your key file / files are being offered using `ssh -vvv user@host`

**Example output:**

```
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Check both remote user home directory and remote `.ssh` directory permissions

For example, the permissions should be:

```
$ls -ld .ssh
drwx------ 2 <owner> <group> 4096 2011-12-29 20:39 .ssh

$ls -ld ~/
drwxr-xr-x 28 <owner> <group> 4096 2011-12-29 20:15 /home/<user>/
```